# Assigning Array Values w/ Pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am practicing basic OOP w/ C++ and while using a pointer I found that I did not need to dereference the pointer to assign a value. Why is this? 
Menu.h:

```
class Menu { public:
int MenuCount;
int NumItems;
Drinks *Items;
```

Menu.cpp

```
Menu::Menu(Drinks a, Drinks b, Drinks c)  {
std::cout << "How many items would you like on this menu? "; std::cin >> NumItems;
Items = new Drinks[NumItems];
Items[0] = a; Items[1] = b; Items[2] = c; // why is it I can assign values by pointer without dereferencing? 
MenuCount = 3;
```

To my understanding I would've had to dereference Items with * prior to assigning a new object to the array, nonetheless this code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [] operator implicitly dereferences the pointer. It hides the pointer arithmetic with arrays, and because arrays decay to pointers to the first element, it works just as well on a pointer as an array.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `Items[0]` is actually the same as `*(Items + 0)` so it is already doing the dereference for you.

Comment: Thank you this was quite helpful as well

Answer (score 0):

```
Menu::Menu(Drinks a, Drinks b, Drinks c)  {
    std::cout << "How many items would you like on this menu? "; std::cin >> NumItems;
    1#  Items = new Drinks[NumItems];
    2#  Items[0] = a; Items[1] = b; Items[2] = c; // why is it I can assign values by pointer without dereferencing? 
    MenuCount = 3;
}
```

1. We are assigning a pointer to a pointer, new Drinks[] will create an array on the heap and return a pointer to it.
2. Items[0] is the same as (*Items + 0), it'll increment the pointer dereference it at that point.